# Categorical analogue of Topology, Bornology...

Tags: category-theory

Given a set $X$, a subcollection $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathfrak{P}(X)$ subject to some conditions may be called a *structure* on $X$ (*e.g.* a Topology, a Bornology, a $\sigma$-Algebra, *etc*...). Moreover, if $(X,\mathcal{C}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{C}_Y)$ denote two structures, applications $f:X\to Y$ either

- *preserve* the structure if $f(A)\in\mathcal{C}_Y$ for all $A\in\mathcal{C}_X$, or if $f^{(-1)}(B)\in\mathcal{C}_X$ for all $B\in\mathcal{C}_Y$ (some covariant/contravariant-like behaviour),
- or *induce* a structure $f^{-1}(\mathcal{C}_Y)=\{f^{-1}(B),\;B\in\mathcal{C}_Y\}$ on $X$ or a structure $f(\mathcal{C}_X)=\{f(A),\;A\in\mathcal{C}_X\}$ on $Y$.

Moreover, it happens that usually, those structures are stable under intersection (that is the intersection of any cardinality of structures is still a structure), which allows us to generate structures with generic subsets $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathfrak{P}(X)$ by : $$\text{struct}(\mathcal{S})=\bigcap_{\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{C}}\mathcal{C}.$$

Another possible thing is to induce a structure on a subset $Z\subset X$ by : $$\mathcal{C}_X\cap Z=\{Z\cap A,\;A\in\mathcal{C}_X\}.$$

In the end, those structures end up defining categories in their own, such as $\textbf{Top}$, $\sigma\textbf{Alg}$, $\textbf{Born}$, *etc*..., where objects are structured sets, and arrows are structure-preserving applications. I was wondering :

> **Is there a categorical generalization of this fact ?** That is, what are the common points between categories such as $\textbf{Top}$, $\sigma\textbf{Alg}$, $\textbf{Born}$, and what are the slight nuances (see the first point in the notion of structure-preserving functions) ?

I know that the power set $\mathfrak{P}(X)$ has a categorical analogue by either

- considering the functor category $[\textbf{1},\textbf{C}]$ (this is the categorical generalization of indicator functions $(\textbf{1}_A)_{A\in\mathfrak{P}(X)}$),
- considering the arrow category $[\textbf{2},\textbf{C}]$ (I have groups regarded as categories in mind here),
- or by simply demanding that the category is posetal.

However, I have no clue how to generalize the *properties* we demand the structures to have in such abstractness. I know Category Theory was invented to unify notions (one example I have in mind is Abelian Categories, which is very general yet contains most "usual" categories), thus I suspect this was already done before. I am clueless on what to search for though.

Comment: I've seen them called *concrete* categories (sets with extra structure as the objects, structure preserving functions as morphisms), or topological categories (if they morover have initial/final structures e.g.; see Preuß and other authors..).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But some categories like $\textbf{Grp}$ are concrete, yet do not fit well with my requirements, as the morphisms indeed preserve the structure, but this structure is not induced by some collection of subsets of the underlying domain and codomain... This makes me think I wasn't clear enough in my original question ; however, I see no way to convey the idea I'm thinking of !

Comment: The fact that they have initial and final structures does distinguish them from algebraic structures like Grp etc. I think.